# Flutter PageView

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to set the start point of a page in pageview?

with code:

```
controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1)
```

I get :

using 1

[image]

using .5 as viewportFraction I get :

[image]

That is what I want to get:

[image]

To use the scroll on start is not a good option because the user can move to the right and it will be on center again. I want the first page to get the most closer to the left margin as possible, and it should not move to the center.

Comment: You can translate first widget or PageView widget based on its current position. Like you can move your pageview on left side programatically by using Transform widget. just an idea what you say :) @Ipotex

Answer (score 0):

**1. To set the starting page of PageView.**

You can use pass `initialPage` in your `PageController` as a parameter to specify the starting index.

For your case:

`controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1, initialPage: 1)`

**2. To answer your question in how to achieve that view.**

I can't think of any solution (for now) but to create each page with two views, but that's not what you want correct?

I don't think trying to solve it with a `viewportFraction` will be helpful for this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Stack to wrap up the PageView, and set the PageView's width like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPvLq.png